# Regularly-executing calls Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I want to write a method in rails that fetch Live gold price from Oanda every second.

```
 def price
      client = OandaAPI::Client::TokenClient.new(:practice, "xxxxxxxxxx") 
      @prices = client.prices(instruments: %w(XAG_USD,XAU_USD,XPT_USD)).get
 end
```

I want to call this method every second. What will be the best approach??

Comment: You have mentioned cron in your tags, have you implemented it to invoke a rake task every second?

Comment: Yes I tried that by using whenever gem. no luck ;(

Comment: Check the crontab log.  If you are using linux, check `/var/log/syslog` for why crons are not triggering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found multiple ways of doing this. I can do it while using Gems like  [delayed_job gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)
[whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

Or we can write a function and start a thread like.

```
while TRUE do
 price()
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the environment to development

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment=development
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do it with a loop:
   `while TRUE do
   price()
   end`
2. You can use [delayed_job gem](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)
3. You can use [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

if whenever dont forget to run command `whenever --update-crontab`